# How to pass string url from Main Activity to next Activity and load url in webView

Tags: java, android, android-intent, webview

I have two Activity, One is Mainactivity and another is Secondactivity. Secondactivity contains Webview that loads local HTML pages from assets folder.

Mainactivity contains buttons labeled as Button A and Button B when pressed would start Secondactivity. I would like to pass the string as URL from Mainactivity to Secondactivity which loads the A.html and B.html when Button A and Button B is pressed.

For now, I have following code in Mainactivity Class

```
 Fragment firstFragment1 = new browser();
            Bundle args1 = new Bundle();
            args1.putString("url1", "file:///android_asset/diploma.html");
            firstFragment1.setArguments(args1);
            moveToFragment(firstFragment1);
            break;
```

and on SecondActivity Class, I have following code

```
    String url1 = getArguments().getString("url1");


    myWebView=(WebView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.webview);
    myWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

    myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
    myWebView.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
    myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    myWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

    myWebView.setInitialScale(1);
    myWebView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    myWebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);

    WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();


    myWebView.loadUrl(url1);


    return rootView;


}
```

Which work for Fragment flawlessly, but how do I make it work for Activity to activity??

Comment: you says you have 2 activity but in your code you use fragment !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In first activity you should put extra argument to intent like this:

```
// I assume Web.class is your second activity
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Web.class); 
intent.putExtra("url", your_url); 
startActivity(intent);
```

**Then in second activity you retrive argument like this:**

```
String url = getIntent().getExtras().getString("url");
webView.load(url);
```

Answer (score 1):

Make one single common activity which load web url

**for example:**

```
public class WebviewActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
Activity mActivity;
WebView webview_;
String title ="";
String url ="";
ProgressDialog dialog;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.help_webview_activity);
    mActivity = this;

    findviews();

    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (bundle != null) {
         title = bundle.getString("title");
         url = bundle.getString("Url");

         setAction();
    }
    else {
        webview_.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    }
}



private void setAction() {

    try {
        //check internet connection first
        if (CommonUtils.isConnectingToInternet(WebviewActivity.this)) { 
            webview_.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            WebSettings webSettings = webview_.getSettings();
            webview_.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
            webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            webview_.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
            webview_.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
            webview_.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(true);
            webview_.loadUrl(url);


        }
        else {

            //alert  - no internet connection
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //print exp
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


private void findviews() {
    webview_ = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.wbview);

}




public class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);

        if(dialog == null){
            dialog = ProgressDialog.show(WebviewActivity.this, null, "Loading...");
            dialog.setCancelable(true);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        if(dialog.isShowing())
            dialog.dismiss();
    }
}
}
```

**Xml code :**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_login_screen"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layoutDirection="ltr"
    tools:context=".activity.WebviewActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar

        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
        android:supportsRtl="false"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">
        <include layout="@layout/header_settinglayout" />
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <WebView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/wbview"
        >

    </WebView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Now you can load any url or html from whole app

From Activity :

```
 if (CommonUtils.isConnectingToInternet(HelpActivity.this)) {
                Intent i = new Intent(HelpActivity.this,WebviewActivity.class);
                i.putExtra("title",getResources().getString(R.string.faqs));
                i.putExtra("Url", "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48594734/how-to-pass-string-url-from-main-activity-to-next-activity-and-load-url-in-webvi");
                startActivity(i);
            }
            else {

                //alert - no internet
            }
```

From Fragment :

```
 if (CommonUtils.isConnectingToInternet(getActivity())) {
                Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(),WebviewActivity.class);
                i.putExtra("title",getResources().getString(R.string.faqs));
                i.putExtra("Url", "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48594734/how-to-pass-string-url-from-main-activity-to-next-activity-and-load-url-in-webvi");
                getActivity().startActivity(i);
            }
            else {

                //alert - no internet
            }
```

**Webview load url**

```
i.putExtra("Url", "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48594734/how-to-pass-string-url-from-main-activity-to-next-activity-and-load-url-in-webvi");
```

**Webview load html from assets directory**

```
 i.putExtra("Url", "file:///android_asset/diploma.html");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using activities, pass the url as a string and get it in the next activity.Like below code

```
Intent intent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("url","somepage.com");
startActivity(intent);
```

In the webView,get it like this

```
String url = getIntent().getStringExtras("url");
webView.load("url");
```

Comment: it Highlight with red color error  on getIntent which says cannot resolve getIntent error.How to solve this.

Comment: Okay Thanks, I used both of your idea and now it works pretty well.

Comment: Please mark the answer as correct if it helped.

Comment: I edited the answer now it wont show the red line

Comment: I thing you should do url encoded to parse and set on web view